# Angular: How to filter out by style?

Tags: angularjs, ng-style, ng-filter

I am new to Angular, so this might seem easy. This is the HTML code:

```
<div>
    Has Time: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="people_filter">
</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="human in people | orderBy:'name' | filter:people_filter ">
        <a href="#!/" ng-style="set_availability(human)">
            {{human.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.set_availability = function(human) {
        if (the human has time) {
            return {
                    color: 'blue'
            };
        }

        return {
            color: 'red'
        };
    };
```

When I inspect element:

```
<a href="#!/" ng-style="set_availability(human)" class="ng-binding" style="color: blue;">
    John Lennon
</a>
```

I have a checkbox with `ng-model="people_filter"`.

If checked, I want it to filter out people who are available.
  If unchecked, I want to list all of the people.

The availability is reflected in `ng-style="blue"` (if yes) or `ng-style="red"` (if no). And it is working, I am able to see `style="color:blue;"` or `style="color:red;"`.

Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: can you share your code in plunker?

Comment: I've read your question, and tried to relate it with the code, thrice. But I can't understand what you're asking. Please show an example of what you want to do.

Comment: please display object structure.

Comment: No. I still don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: try this `ng-style="{ 'color' : (the human has time) ? 'blue : 'red' }"` but i don't know what do mean about `the human has time`

Comment: @JBNizet, updated post

Comment: @Hadi, updated code

Comment: @kartikajas, updated code

Comment: You're not thinking it correctly. A filter doesn't work on DOM elements. It works on the objects stored in the array of your controller. The style is only generated by the template, from the model, too. So, you must not think about "filter our blue items". You must think about "filter out available persons". Pass a function to the filter filter, and make that function take a person as argument, and return false if people_filter is true and the person is available.

Comment: @JBNizet, I got it now: it won't work on DOM elements - one new thing to know about Angular filter. Will work on your suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to change the color of the style based on the output of the function call. Please check this out.

```
$availableHuman = [];
$scope.set_availability = function(human) {
            if (human.time) {                    
                availableHuman.push(human); 
                return {
             "color:"+blue+";
                };
            } 

            return {
                 "color:"+red+";
            };
        };




 <div class="list" ng-repeat="human in availableHuman">
  {{ human }}
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the code. I don't want to change to color, just want to filter out according to its style

Comment: if the human has time, then u can push that human to an array. is this what you are looking up for?

Comment: I wanted to have it worked with DOM, apparently, it won't.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: you can then use for loop to print that values in the dom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146211/discussion-between-kartikajas-and-samkirklandwa).